# [3+1]-Cycloadditions of Sulfur Ylides and 1,3-Dipoles(?)

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry

My question is basically regarding the stereoselectivity of the situation.

I am not being able to decide on the positioning of the sulfur ylide with proper justification.

In the attached hand-drawn image, I have considered the (1'-oxoalkyl) group away from the alkyl group $\alpha$ to the carbonyl. The other possible orientation is to direct in on the same side as the alkyl group,  but coming out of the page.

Each positioning leads to a different outcome, which is why I drew the final product with a "wiggly" bond.

Furthermore, the transition state that I have drawn really seems sketchy, and I feel I need some guidance on that part.

[[3 + 1]- and [3 + 2]-Cycloadditions of Azaoxyallyl Cations and Sulfur Ylides](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.orglett.6b01194)

[image]

Comment: I can't read this paper. Do the authors think that this proceeds via a carbene? That carbon in the transition state has too many bonds to seem reasonable...